# How to use BuiltInParameters in react-native-app-auth to display auth screen in full screen

Tags: ios, react-native

React native have library for external auth provide & below is configuration:-

```
import {
  authorize,
} from 'react-native-app-auth';
const config = {
  issuer: 'https://xxxx.com:xxxx/',
  clientId: 'xxxxx-ipad-local', 
  redirectUrl: 'com.oms:/oauthredirect',
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'roles'],
  additionalParameters: {
    display : "page"
  }
};
```

Ask is to show auth login screen to full screen as shown in options below from library which is not working. :-

[image]

Can the login window which appears from library https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth is customisable, As per library there are some option as shown in ablove screenshot but seems not working. Any clue will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the options.

```
iosCustomBrowser?: 'safari' | 'chrome' | 'opera' | 'firefox';
androidAllowCustomBrowsers?: ('chrome' | 'chromeCustomTab' | 'firefox' | 'firefoxCustomTab' | 'samsung' | 'samsungCustomTab')[]
```

Your config will be like this for iOS as an example:

```
const config = {
  issuer: 'https://xxxx.com:xxxx/',
  clientId: 'xxxxx-ipad-local', 
  // iOS requires a trailing slash on redirectUrl
  redirectUrl: 'com.oms:/oauthredirect/',
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'roles'],
  additionalParameters: {
    display : "page"
  },
  iosCustomBrowser: 'safari'
};
```

This will open the website in Safari with the same behaviour `Linking` opens a URL. You'll have to manage the redirect back to your app when you complete the authentication.